# Can I remove empty entries in Doc FX ? Stuffs I did/can not write xml comments for

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, docfx

I'm using Doc FX for a C# project but I end up with some empty entries, like this:

[image: DOC Fx screenshot]

Which is an issue considering I'm pretty sure I cannot write my own xml comment for the **int** type^^
They are also some stuffs in my API that I didn't document on purpose.

Is there any way to get rid of those ?
Thanks a lot!